# Magento show partial page (form) instead of full webpage

Tags: magento, templates, configuration, module

I would like to show only a form for registration of an account on Magento instead of the full webpage including the form.
Could I reach this result by adding a configuration for the single form page to /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml? Or should I extend or copy the controller and build a similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an empty page layout that Magento provides. Take a look at the Mage_Page layout: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml.

So in your customer.xml layout, do something like:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <update handle="page_empty" />
</customer_account_create>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try remove

```
$this->loadLayout();  
$this->renderLayout();
```

from your controller action code